# Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view

Tags: java, android

[image]

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'packageRelease' property 'outputDirectory' during up-to-date check.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\oMaR Waleed\Desktop\release\android.gradle\4.0-rc-1\fileContent\fileContent.lock'.

im trying to build apk

Comment: try disabling the anti virus

Comment: run android studio as administrator and try..

Answer (score 0):

**This is mostly an antivirus issue**

One solution that worked for me

> **Try disabling your antivirus and do it again**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your Android Studio and also generate a new Key path.

Answer (score -1):

**Run android studio as administrator** its worked for me.

Comment: Running a user application like Android Studio as administrator is wrong. It might solve the problem, but it is not how you should solve it.